# Evaluating a math expression given in string format

Tags: java, beginner, math-expression-eval

I am currently working on building a calculator using Java and JavaFX to practice my coding skills. I wrote the following methods to evaluate a given expression.

What can I improve? Is there anything you would recommend me to change to optimize my program?

---

```
public static String evaluate(String expression) {
    char[] tokens = expression.toCharArray();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    String s = "";

    String operator = "";
    String firstNum = "";
    String secondNum = "";

    boolean operationOnQueue = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(tokens[i])) {
            s += Character.toString(tokens[i]);
        } else {
            list.add(s);
            list.add(Character.toString(tokens[i]));

            if (operationOnQueue) {
                operationOnQueue = false;
                secondNum = s;

                list.set(list.lastIndexOf(firstNum), eval(firstNum, operator, secondNum));
                list.remove(list.lastIndexOf(operator));
                list.remove(list.lastIndexOf(secondNum));
            }

            if (tokens[i] == '*' || tokens[i] == '/') {
                operationOnQueue = true;

                operator = Character.toString(tokens[i]);
                firstNum = list.get(list.lastIndexOf(operator) - 1);
            }

            s = "";
        }

        if (i == tokens.length - 1 && s.length() > 0) {
            list.add(s);

            if (list.get(list.size() - 2).equals("*") || list.get(list.size() - 2).equals("/")) {
                firstNum = list.get(list.size() - 3);
                operator = list.get(list.size() - 2);
                secondNum = list.get(list.size() - 1);

                list.set(list.size() - 3, eval(firstNum, operator, secondNum));
                list.remove(list.size() - 2);
                list.remove(list.size() - 1);
            }
        }
    }


    while (list.size() > 1) {
        firstNum = list.get(0);
        operator = list.get(1);
        secondNum = list.get(2);

        list.set(0, eval(firstNum, operator, secondNum));
        list.remove(2);
        list.remove(1);
    }

    return list.get(0);
}
```

```
public static String eval(String a, String operator, String b) {
    double r = 0;

    switch (operator) {
        case "/":
            r += Double.parseDouble(a) / Double.parseDouble(b);
            break;
        case "*":
            r += Double.parseDouble(a) * Double.parseDouble(b);
            break;
        case "-":
            r += Double.parseDouble(a) - Double.parseDouble(b);
            break;
        case "+":
            r += Double.parseDouble(a) + Double.parseDouble(b);
            break;
    }

    return Double.toString(r);
}
```

---

These are the results of my tests. The first line is the string inputted, along with the answer to the expression. The second line is the output of the program.

```
8+4/2+10*3+5*10 = 90
90.0

60*60+8+384/7/4-44*26 = 2477.71
2477.714285714286

64/16*18-51*7+5 = -280
-280.0

64/16*18-5100*7+5 = -35623
-35623.0

7325+92+44/4+57-84 = 7401
7401.0

14+54/9+1 = 21
21.0

7*4/7+9+12*3 = 49
49.0
```

Answer (score 3):

### How does it work?

Seems to be working now. What I can't understand is how :)

Code should be readable and easily understandable by humans as well. You might even be one of the humans that have to work with code that you wrote a year or more ago..

There is a lot going on in the code that I cannot tell why it's there and what its use is.

For example:

```
 if (operationOnQueue) {
                    operationOnQueue = false;
                    secondNum = s;

                    list.set(list.lastIndexOf(firstNum), eval(firstNum, operator, secondNum));
                    list.remove(list.lastIndexOf(operator));
                    list.remove(list.lastIndexOf(secondNum));
                }
```

I can read the code and see what it will do, but why? I have no clue.

So either try to explain the why in comments, or re-write the code to be more self-explanatory.

(Btw your code looks a bit like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm.)

### Try to break big methods into smaller ones

You `evaluate` does a few things. The `while` loop in the end seems like a good candidate for a separate method. The second `if` in the `for` loop as well.

### Don't repeat yourself

There are a few `Character.toString(tokens[i])` in the code. It's easier to read if you extract that to a variable, for example `String currentToken = Character.toString(tokens[i])`

### Handling error cases

What if the input is not a correct expression?

For example: `14+54/9+`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at Math.evaluate(Math.java:64)
    at Math.main(Math.java:96)
```

BTW: for more interesting links / implementations see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/114601/461499

Answer (score 2):

There is one big issue in your setup, which reduces the usability, readability and quality of your code.

### Single Responsibility Principle

Your function does both (1) parsing and evaluation, and (2) printing results.

> ```
> public static String evaluate(String expression) 
> {
>     // .. parse expression
>     // .. evaluate the expression tree
>     // .. print the result as string
> }
> ```

You have even managed to combine the evaluation and printing.

> ```
> public static String eval(String a, String operator, String b) 
> {
>     // evaluate operation
>     // format the result to string
> }
> ```

You should refactor your code.

Parsing and evaluation:

```
public static Double evaluate(String expression) 
{
    // .. parse expression
    // .. evaluate the expression tree
}

public static Double eval(Double a, Operators operator, Double b) 
{
    // .. evaluate operation
}

public enum Operators { Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide }
```

Printing

```
public static String print(Double value) 
{
    // .. print value
}
```

---

And there's that infamous [division by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137989/java-division-by-zero-doesnt-throw-an-arithmeticexception-why) amongst other possible edge cases you should think about:

> `r += Double.parseDouble(a) / Double.parseDouble(b);`

Answer (score 0):

To make your code short, understandable, elegant, maintainable, and fast, I recommend to:

- implement separately syntax and semantics
- for syntax part, construct recursive descent parser.
- read something on theory, starting from [Bacus-Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)
- learn examples on [Github recursive descent parser](https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=recursive%20descent%20parser&type=Repositories)
- ask questions at Stackoverflow. Tag them with [recursive-descent].